# Pandas function hat prints the value of a column from antoher data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A newby here! I have a df that looks like this

```html
key1  parentID  fullname  ssn  birthdate
0  1  19  Verlie Bailey  496-35-2171  Fri-2011-06-10-17:28:19
1  2  10  Bernarda Tippett  532-36-2171  Sun-2016-05-29-11:47:28
2  3  27  Cecelia Hartnett  532-24-8961  Wed-2010-06-02-00:34:02
3  4  4  Kristin Hobbs  661-99-7959  Thu-2011-01-13-01:47:54
4  5  16  Enriqueta Jolley  661-35-9909  Wed-2010-09-29-08:44:12
5  6  40  Teresa Devine  125-97-2946  Sun-2015-12-27-16:39:14
6  7  15  Graham Deloach  661-36-1624  Sat-2012-07-21-12:04:41
7  8  48  Randolph Lasalle  893-36-8961  Sat-2012-12-01-15:23:08
8  9  4  Catharine Hobbs  323-36-8852  Sun-2014-03-09-09:02:52
9  10  37  Elnora Shippee  125-35-2998  Sat-2012-03-31-23:25:16
10  11  26  Latoya Purvis  532-97-9974  Mon-2012-07-09-17:01:17
```

And I need to create a function that prints the first name of the parent when I give it someone's fullname. I expect `f('Catharine Hobbs')` to print `Kristin`.

I have tried these, but none of them has worked:

```html
    parentId = 0
    for line in family:
        if line[2] == fullname:
            parentId = line[1]
    for line in employee:
        if line[1] == parentId:
            return line[2].split(' ')[0]
```

```html
def f(x):
    parent = 0
    for i in family.fullname:
        if i == x:
            parent = family.parentID
        return parent
```

I know it's poor coding, but I don't understand either why it doesn't work and haven't seen something like what I need on the internet.

Comment: I don't want to sound nasty but you should probably spend some time reading around `pandas`. You're treating the dataframe like a nested list and it _really_ goes against the grain of how the library is supposed to be used.

Comment: @roganjosh I do know that! But I haven't seen anything like what I need in the books or manuals. What I've tried has given me all sorts of errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a self-join:

```
pd.merge(df, df[['key1', 'fullname']], left_on='parentID', right_on='key1', how='left')
```

It should give you a new column with parents' names mapped to each individual, along with bunch of extra columns, which you can filter out as per your requirements.

Comment: Didn't work :( `TypeError: merge() got multiple values for argument 'how'`. Then I removed the last how and got this `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: Can you provide the code for generating the initial rows of your dataframe? It would be easier to debug if I can recreate the format. I had just tried this one on a sample dataframe and it worked.

Comment: It seems like I can't paste the content here, but take a look at it https://screenshots.firefox.com/85Hqu16HWtrCHn2N/localhost

Comment: Try changing `family.merge(...)` to `pd.merge(...)`

Answer (score -1):

Your functions are pretty close to how I would approach this requirement. Approach: given a string, if that string appears at least once in the column `fullname`, then return the first part of the string, split by a space.

```
def get_first_name(fullname):
    if fullname in df['fullname'].values:
        return fullname.split(' ')[0]

get_first_name('Verlie Bailey')
# 'Verlie'

get_first_name('Catharine Hobbs')
# 'Catharine'

get_first_name('asdf')
# None
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `pandas` _at all_? Searching through the DF is pointless, just convert the names to a set and check for membership if you're doing down this route.

Comment: @roganjosh, that's a legitimate point - thanks for the feedback. First, I believe it is faster to check for membership directly in a numpy array compared to building a set out of that array and then check for membership in that set. Second, your set suggestion is less flexible than writing a function that operates on a DataFrame. It's easy to modify (and probably rename) the `get_first_name` function to perform other reporting or aggregation features on the DF, whereas just checking for membership in a set of names isn't extensible.

Comment: It's getting late for me to set up a test but "First, I believe it is faster to check for membership directly in a numpy array compared to building a set out of that array and then check for membership in that set." is almost certainly not true for 3 method calls (it may be for a one-off) :)